# Extracting gps coordinates from exif info of photo images

Tags: import, image

I need to extract the GPS coordinates from the Exif information of a series of image. This used to work in Mathematica 11.0.0 (on MacOSX):

Import[zf, {"Exif", {"GPSLatitude", "GPSLongitude", "GPSAltitude", 
   "DateTime"}}]

(where zf contains the file path to the photo image).

Unfortunately in Mathematica 11.0.1 this does no longer work. I have seen a previous question/answer using image=Import[zf,"ImageWithExif"] and then digging out the values using complicated manipulations of Options[image,Metainformation]. Is this a bug in 11.0.1? or did my previous variant work by chance but is not syntactically correct?

Should also add that using image=Import[zf,"ImageWithExif"] and then extracting the info with Options[image,Metainformation] is terribly inefficient. The original variant was much faster.

Comment: Can you upload a sample of these images somewhere?

Comment: Here's a file:

https://oc.bgc-jena.mpg.de/index.php/s/veah157zFpjdNJh

Answer (score 3):

The solution is much simpler: I get the GPS info directly with:

Import[zf,{{"GeoPosition","DateTime"}}]

This is also very efficient. Still strange why the old syntax does not work anymore.

Comment: However, this is does not work for particular locations - see this picture:

https://oc.bgc-jena.mpg.de/index.php/s/ptzW3W9JyOlPVZv

Using the Import[zf,{{GeoPosition}}] retrieves a corrupt GPSAltitude, even though it is correctly listed in the EXIF info of the file. This definitely is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the following image and save it somewhere (in my case to `f:\test.jpg`)

[image]

Then I execute (MMA 11.0.1):

```
Import["F:\\test.jpg", {"Exif", {"GPSLatitude", "GPSLongitude", 
   "GPSAltitude", "DateTime"}}]
```

The output is (contains gps data):

```
<|"Make" -> "Apple", "Model" -> "iPhone 4", 
 "Orientation" -> <|"CameraTopOrientation" -> Top, 
   "Mirrored" -> False|>, "XResolution" -> 72, "YResolution" -> 72, 
 "ResolutionUnit" -> "inch", "Software" -> "4.3.5", 
 "DateTime" -> 
  DateObject[{2011, 9, 4}, TimeObject[{12, 51, 11.}, TimeZone -> 1.], 
   TimeZone -> 1.], "ExposureTime" -> Quantity[1/3016, "Seconds"], 
 "FNumber" -> "f/2.8", "ExposureProgram" -> "Auto", 
 "ISOSpeedRatings" -> 80, "ExifVersion" -> "2.21", 
 "DateTimeOriginal" -> 
  DateObject[{2011, 9, 4}, TimeObject[{12, 51, 11.}, TimeZone -> 1.], 
   TimeZone -> 1.], 
 "DateTimeDigitized" -> 
  DateObject[{2011, 9, 4}, TimeObject[{12, 51, 11.}, TimeZone -> 1.], 
   TimeZone -> 1.], "ComponentsConfiguration" -> "YCbCr", 
 "ShutterSpeedValue" -> 11.5587, "ApertureValue" -> 2.8, 
 "MeteringMode" -> "Multi-segment", 
 "FlashInfo" -> <|"FlashUsed" -> False, 
   "FlashFiringStatus" -> "No strobe return detection function", 
   "FlashMode" -> Missing["Unknown"], "FlashFunctionPresent" -> True, 
   "RedEyeCorrection" -> False|>, 
 "FocalLength" -> Quantity[3.8, "Millimeters"], 
 "FlashpixVersion" -> "1.00", "ColorSpace" -> "RGBColor", 
 "PixelXDimension" -> 1024, "PixelYDimension" -> 765, 
 "SensingMethod" -> "One-chip color area", 
 "CustomRendered" -> Missing["Disputed"], "ExposureMode" -> "Auto", 
 "WhiteBalance" -> "Auto", "SceneCaptureType" -> "Standard", 
 "GPSLatitudeRef" -> "North", 
 "GPSLatitude" -> Quantity[38.9098, "AngularDegrees"], 
 "GPSLongitudeRef" -> "East", 
 "GPSLongitude" -> Quantity[1.43867, "AngularDegrees"], 
 "GPSAltitudeRef" -> "AboveSeaLevel", 
 "GPSAltitude" -> Quantity[Select[0, NumberQ[#1] &], "Meters"], 
 "GPSTimeStamp" -> TimeObject[{11, 7, 47.}, TimeZone -> 1.], 
 "GPSImgDirectionRef" -> "True direction", 
 "GPSImgDirection" -> Quantity[5338/65, "AngularDegrees"], 
 "GPSDateStamp" -> DateObject[{2011, 9, 4}]|>
```

Comment: Hmm, trying to take the image directly from imgur fails: `Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qioMG.jpg", {"Exif", {"GPSLatitude", "GPSLongitude", "GPSAltitude", "DateTime"}}]`. I wonder why...

Comment: Indeed, this syntax is broken under Mathematica 11.0.1 on MacOS.

Comment: @J. M. I am also confused that it does not work with image from imgur. From HD it works.